# Rotate multi line (series of points) to match region

Tags: rotation, geometry, coordinates, line, multiline

I have an arbitrary multiline (series of XY points) starting at (0, 0). 
The task is to recalculate all positions in that way, so the last point would lay on a predefined edge (Y value). See illustration.

[image: illustration]

Is there any algorithm to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the last point has coordinates `(xe, ye)`, then direction angle from origin to that point is

```
fie =  Atan2(ye, xe)
```

Distance from origin to tha point is

```
len = Sqrt(ye*ye + xe*xe)
```

Wanted y-position is `yw`, so direction angle is

```
fiw = Arcsin(yw / len)
```

So you need to [rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) all points by angle difference

```
dfi = fiw - fie  = Arcsin(yw / len) - Atan2(ye, xe)
```

Comment: Cheers! That's what I need.